# VB.NET MouseClick Event Handler is not working with User Controls

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, event-handling, click, mouseevent

The user controls are being added to a panel and as they are created their properties are set and the event handler is added to each one. I have one user control, they are distinguished by different 'Views' (*Grid, Job, Time, Day, Week*)

My problem is with the *Job* view as when this view is active the control has a property called *Job* (Just realised how confusing these names can be) and *Job* can be 1 or 0 (1 being True/Yes/Active and 0 the opposite)

```
    Private Sub PaintJobs()
    For Row As Integer = 1 To CalendarRows - 1 Step 2
        For Col As Integer = 1 To CalendarCols - 1 Step 2

            Dim J As New CalendarCell
            J.View = CalendarCell.CalendarCellView.Job
            J.Job = 1
            pnlCalendar.Controls.Add(J)
            AddHandler J.MouseClick, AddressOf CalendarClick

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The code above adds controls to the panel on top of other controls of different *View* values (Onto *Grid* control) and looks like this:
[Image of the calendar, the *Jobs are in red*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp5Jw.png)

And the CalendarClick event code:

```
    Private Sub CalendarClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim J As CalendarCell = sender
    If J.Job = 1 Then
        MsgBox("First if passed")
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            MsgBox("Left button clicked")
        ElseIf e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            MsgBox("Right button clicked")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time, if you need anymore information just ask below and Ill be glad to supply it :)

Comment: I cant tell what that picture is supposed to tell us or what the UC is comprised of, but clicking on something on/in the UserControl wont fire the UC Click event.

Comment: Have you explicitly created/raised the event from within your user control class?

Comment: The picture shows the panel and all the different UCs forming a calendar, the red ones are the ones that Im trying to add an event handler to, its just to help visualise what's going on. The event is fired from the form that the controls are being created on. On the UC there is a picture box, I will try and add the even handler to that.

Comment: Wow thank you for opening my eyes to it, raising the even from the UC works. But, although there is now a message box saying "Left button clicked", you cannot open another form (Form1.show()) from a UC... So 1 problem down and another one to go I guess

Comment: Problem fixed. Thank you all

Comment: Its hard to tell a picturebox from a label via a picture.